# How to check if an item exist in list and has value

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a model classes like below

```
public class A
{
 public string Name{get;set;}
 public string Value{get;set;}
}
public class B
{
 public List<A>Items{get;set;}
}
```

The below json will be deserialized to class B

```
{
"Items":[
{
  "Name":"Food Name"
  "Value":"Fries"
},
{
  "Name":"Weapon Name"
  "Value":"Gun"
},
{
  "Name":"Vehicle Name"
  "Value":"Car"
},
{
  "Name":"Pet Name"
  "Value":"Mewto"
},
{
  "Name":"Personal Name"
  "Value":"Leo"
}]}
```

Once the values are deserialized to the class B, I need to validate whether the list item contains ***Name*** Food Name,Personal Name,Weapon Name and Car Name and ***Value*** for these mentioned items are not null or empty. What is the best approach for this?

Comment: @Austin that is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go for something like

```
List<A> Items = //however you get the list
string[] names = {"Food Name","Personal Name","Weapon Name", "Car Name"};
foreach (string s in names)
{
    var item = Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == s);
    if (item == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Value))
    {
        // handle the missing data
        break;
    }
}
```

This is likely an ugly solution, but it should work. Also take note, that this doesn't check for any other items in the list. You could have an item where `Name` is `George` and `Value` could be `Potato`, just as long as you also have the items with correct names.

Comment: OP wants to know if the item list would be valid, rather than handle the missing data.

Comment: Yes, and handling the missing data can be for example notifying the user about invalid list, sending an error report to a webserver or shutting down a nuclear reactor. I can't extrapolate the correct procedure based on the question, so I just added a placeholder to 'handle' it.

Comment: That makes sense but based on the question I assumed he only wanted to get a boolean value indicating if the entire list is valid or not. Either way, it's a very small thing I pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

If it can be only one item of each name

```
var jsonParsed=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<B>(json);

var valid=  jsonParsed.Items.Count(i=> names.Contains(i.Name) 
                && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Value))==names.Length;
```

but if the several items are allowed, it will take 2 steps. At first we will check values, after this - names

```
var valid=false;
 
var notValidValues =jsonParsed.Items.Any(i=> names.Contains(i.Name) 
                          && string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Value));
    
if (!notValidValues) valid = jsonParsed.Items.Where(i => names.Contains(i.Name))
                                    .GroupBy(i => i.Name).Count() == names.Length;
```

Comment: Seems cleaner than my solution. One question, mostly for me to learn, since this is comparing counts on the lists, if the `jsonParsed` would have two items where `Name` is "Food Name" and none with "Personal Name", would this catch the error?

Comment: @Sami Good question. I was thinking about this too. But I don't  know all details. But as well instead of "Weapon Name" can be "Wepon Name" for example. It will be the same kind of error.

Comment: True, so some validation should be implemented in any case..

Comment: @Sami  Sorry,  Only now I understood what you meant.  I don' t know if it can be several weapons for example. But just in case I updated my solution.

Comment: It is possible to check values and names in a single step. Check my answer for that.

Comment: @Despacito2 I can put  my code in one line too, but I don't see what I can gain from it.

Comment: It's not just that. It does the entire validation process in the fewest steps possible while yours first validates one part and then the other. My terminology isn't the best to describe what I mean but I personally just find it more readable that way but opinions differ.

Comment: @Despacito2 Nobody knows how many steps linq makes. The fastest way is to use foreach loop since everytning is under control then.

Comment: that's a fair point.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a number solid solutions. I did something similar to Sami. Since you're deserializing to B, I created List to represent that. Not the most elegant, but it works. Hope you find what works well for you

```
//Sample list
var newB = new B
{
    Items = new List<A>
    {
        new A{Name = "Food Name", Value = "Fries" },
        new A{Name = "Weapon Name", Value = "Gun" },
        new A{ Name = "Weapon Name", Value = "" },
    }
};


foreach (var item in newB.Items)
{
   string[] vals = { item.Name, item.Value };   

   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(vals[0]) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(vals[1]))
  {
    //Handle missing vals
    Console.WriteLine("We have a missing val");
  }
  else
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Good to go");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] mandatoryNames = { "Food Name", "Personal Name", "Weapon Name", "Car Name" };
var valid = mandatoryNames
    .All(mandatoryName => items
        .Any(item => item.Name == mandatoryName
                     && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value)));
```